# GoogleApiClient for Google Login

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-signin

I've researched for a while and have found nothing that helps.  I am almost done with my app and i wish to add Google Login features.  I'm not asking for anyone to right my code for me.  I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  Every website, including the android developer website, has been no help.  Any help from you is appreciated.  Again, I only need to be pointed in the right direction, not have my code written for me.

Did what the answer told me to and got this error code. First it told me to change to 10.2.1, then 9.0.0:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Here's my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'cm'
        keyPassword 'cr3101120$$'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/Carter/AndroidStudioProjects/ColorMatch/release.jks')
        storePassword 'cr3101120$$'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "carsquared.colormatch"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's the main Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. please Signup here 
   https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In
2. create app and fill package name and SHA1
3. SHA1 generate From your system like this
   a. generate signed apk.(With JKS file)
   b. open cmd select following path "AndroidSetup\jre\bin"
   c. run this coomand  `keytool -exportcert -list -v  -keystore E:\JKSFile\GoEthno.jks E:\JKSFile\GoEthno.jks = your jks file path`
   d.Copy SHA-1 and paste above definde place
4. Enable Google Sign in From above url
5. Generate the Google service json
6. Place Google service json in app folder in android project

Add this dependencies dependencies

`{ // .. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1' // glide is added to load the g+ profile image. Ignore if you want compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' } 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

and you can see rest of code for google sign in here
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: Add this dependencies
dependencies {

    // ..
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
 
    // glide is added to load the g+ profile image. Ignore if you want
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

}
 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I did all that and i got this error code.  First it told me to 'update' it to 10.2.1. So I did. then it told me to 'update' to 9.0.0. Here's the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: added it to the original post.

Comment: i am asking for the main gradle file @carter

Comment: ah my bad, i added it.

Comment: replace this in main gradle file
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0'
add this in app gradle

Comment: hope it will help you.